# 'make_unique' is not a member of 'std'

Tags: c++, cmake, g++, c++17

I'm using g++-9 and c++17 on Linux Mint 19.2. The compiler is literally telling me to include `<memory>` adjacent to where I'm already including it:

```
/home/luke/workspace/crab/Src/Brain/EpisodicMemory.cpp:2:1: note: ‘std::make_unique’ is defined in header ‘<memory>’; did you forget to ‘#include <memory>’?
    1 | #include "EpisodicMemory.h"
  +++ |+#include <memory>
    2 | #include <memory>
```

I can produce the error with this minimal example:

```
#include <memory>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::unique_ptr<int> test = std::make_unique<int>(4);
    return 0;
}
```

Really don't know what's going on.

Here is my CMakeLists.txt (since you don't believe I'm using c++17):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(crab)
find_package(Qt5Widgets)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -pthread -Wall -O0 -g -fsanitize=address -std=c++17 -fPIC")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${Qt5Widgets_EXECUTABLE_COMPILE_FLAGS}")
include_directories(${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})
#file(GLOB BRAIN_FILES Brain/*.cpp Brain/*.h)
#add_executable(crab ${BRAIN_FILES} main.cpp)
add_executable(crab main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(crab Qt5::Widgets)
```

I think linking Qt might be changing my compiler settings but I don't know why that would happen

Comment: I'm able to repro if I force C++11 (which did not have make_unique) are you sure that you are using C++17? https://godbolt.org/z/EWvVEQ

Comment: [No repro](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b1a2eeb490a6f22)

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` is introduced in C++11, `std::make_unique()` in C++14. I suppose you're compiling C++11

Comment: I'm using c++17: set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -pthread -Wall -O0 -g -fsanitize=address -std=c++17 -fPIC")

Comment: Do you have `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)` in your CMake? `target_compile_features`? Please [edit] the question and post your full CMakeLists.txt

Comment: I've added the full CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Suggestion: comment the `std::unique_ptr`/`std::make_unique()` row, add inclusion of `iostream` and add the following line: `std::cout << __cplusplus << std::endl;`. Then say us the value that is printed.

Comment: It's 201103 ~~~

Comment: @Luke - No doubt: you're compiling C++11. Maybe it's the order of the set instructions in CMakeLists.txt? Maybe you can try with `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${Qt5Widgets_EXECUTABLE_COMPILE_FLAGS}")` before and `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -pthread -Wall -O0 -g -fsanitize=address -std=c++17 -fPIC")` after

Comment: I seem to have fixed it by replacing -std=c++17 with set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

Comment: @Luke - Great! And I suppose that, now, from `__cplusplus` you get `201703`.

Comment: @Luke You can make that an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fixed it by replacing -std=c++17 with set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

Comment: for others new to cmake, i had a top level cmakelists that i set this for, and didnt realize lower level cmakelists still had standard == 11, which made those executables compile with 11 instead of 17

Comment: `set( CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14 )` also works for me